# flutter Listview builder overflow

Tags: flutter

i am getting render box error for the ListView.Builder.
Expanded is not working as well,
i.  tried many different this.
still this error not. going.
how to. solve this ?
[erorr can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1LHt.jpg)

i want to view the data without the render overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened. because of Listview.builder is not getting enough space.
to solve this use:-

```
shrinkWrap: true
```

it will help Listviewwbuilder to fit with available space.